# Using Regular Expression to Replace Function with Changing Parameters

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will allow me to replace PHPs mail function with my own. In all places, I pass 4 parameters to the mail function like below:

```
mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

I would like to run a regular expression that would replace the mail function in these instances. I would like the result to look like this:

```
custom_mail_tool($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Sometimes the parameters have different names, so I can't do a regular find and replace. I.e. `mail($user_email,$subject_line,$content,$headers);`

Any help would be great!

Comment: Are you doing this in a code editor?  Why not just find and replace `mail(` with `custom_mail_tool(`?

Comment: Sometimes i use the word mail( in other places throughout the site.

Comment: To build a code for that, I suggest you to use the tokenizer to avoid all the php syntax traps (quotes, heredoc, nowdoc, comments)

Comment: Fair enough, Amal's answer should work then.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off job, then the following search pattern should suffice:

```
mail(\([$\w]+,[$\w]+,[$\w]+,[$\w]+\);)
```

Use this as the replacement pattern:

```
custom_mail_tool$1
```

[**Regex101 demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wJ2jU7)

Comment: I don't think he's trying to use php to edit his php code, but the regex should be roughly the same.

Comment: @WilliamKunkel: not sure of that!

Comment: Hi all, using the regex find and replace function in dreamweaver :)

Comment: @user2905222: I don't use Dreamweaver, but I think this should work. The search and replace option should look something like [this](http://www.peachpit.com/content/images/chap4_9780321822529/elementLinks/04fig37.jpg). Make sure you **☑** "Use regular expression" checkbox.